# Python changes path after loops is done

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I try to read all excel files in a directory to merge them into one df, which seems to work fine (the dataframe is correctly created)

How ever it seems that python is trying perform the loop a second time after all the files have been read, but in different location where the excel files do not exist and I get a traceback for 'file not found' which is obvious cause the files are not saved in this location.

It jumps from 'C:/users/folder/folder' to 'C:/users' and tries to loop again over all files, any idea why this happens?

The code I am using is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import os

path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)

files_xlsx = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == 'xlsx']

df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files_xlsx:
    data = pd.read_excel(f)
    df = df.append(data)

print(df)
```

Here is the full traceback I get:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.2.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 58606 --file "C:/Users/Home/OneDrive/Ops/Media Management/Media Kitchen/Rezepte aktuell vom 10.05.2021/Rezepte Alphabetisch xlsx/XLSX merg.py"
pydev debugger: process 22124 is connecting
Connected to pydev debugger (build 202.6948.78)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\header_footer.py:48: UserWarning: Cannot parse header or footer so it will be ignored
  warn("""Cannot parse header or footer so it will be ignored""")
...
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\header_footer.py:48: UserWarning: Cannot parse header or footer so it will be ignored
  warn("""Cannot parse header or footer so it will be ignored""")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.2.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1448, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.2.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Home/OneDrive/Ops/Media Management/Media Kitchen/Rezepte aktuell vom 10.05.2021/Rezepte Alphabetisch xlsx/XLSX merg.py", line 46, in <module>
    data = pd.read_excel(f)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 336, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1071, in __init__
    ext = inspect_excel_format(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 949, in inspect_excel_format
    with get_handle(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 651, in get_handle
    handle = open(handle, ioargs.mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\$ACHR3-00.00.xlsx'
python-BaseException
```

Comment: Python wouldn't do that on its own, can you please share the full traceback of the error and the exact code you are running that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I've updated the post hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, can you put `print("Current Path:", os.getcwd())` before the `for` loop and inspect its output? Is that the path you are looking for?

Comment: Yes that's the path

Comment: and it is not the same as `C:\Users`? If not, I'm afraid I don't know the cause. I run the same exact code snippet you shared and didn't get a folder-changing behaviour.

Comment: Therefore, only thing I can say is there is more to your code and those result in this behaviour. As said, the code snippet you shared doesn't do that.

Comment: No it's 'C:/Users/Home/OneDrive/Ops/Media Management/Media Kitchen/Rezepte aktuell vom 10.05.2021/Rezepte Alphabetisch xlsx/file' and that's what it should be, but after the loop finishes in this location it somehow swithes to 'C:/Users'

Comment: I know that's why 'm so confused why it does this

Comment: Traceback says that's the line 46; if you can share the whole code as it is, perhaps we can point to the reason. If this is not possible, I'm sorry I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I just deleted the comments I had in my code (that's why its line 46) but I will update the code section with the whole code but I don't think it makes any difference